# Swing: detect Enter in JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've tried using getInputMap() + getActionMap() on a JComboBox and it seems to have no effect.

I've tried addActionListener() / addItemListener() on a JComboBox and I can't seem to distinguish a change of selection from someone pressing the Return/Enter key.

Any suggestions? In my application, I want the Return/Enter key to be stronger than just selecting, it's a selecting + applying action.

---

Here's my code to setup the key binding. It works fine (e.g. `note("hit ENTER")` is called) when component is a `JList`, but doesn't work when component is a JComboBox.

```
private void setupApplyProfile(final JComponent component, final MyComboBoxModel mcbm)
{   
    String enterAction = "applyItem";
    KeyStroke enterKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
    component.getInputMap().put(enterKey, enterAction);
    component.getActionMap().put(enterAction, new AbstractAction()
    {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            note("hit ENTER");
            applySelectedProfile(mcbm);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How were you using getActionMap()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, this seems to work: `note("cb editor action")` gets called when I hit Enter in the combo box field.

```
        comboBox.getEditor().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                note("cb editor action");
            }               
        });
```

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work with Substance :(, the listener should be added to combobox itself.

Answer (score 3):

> In my application, I want the Return/Enter key to be stronger than just selecting, it's a selecting + applying action.

If I understand the question you can use the following:

```
comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

The ActionEvent and ItemEvents will only be fired when an item is selected from the drop down list when you use the mouse or the enter key. The eEvents will not be fired if you navigate the drop down list using the up/down arrow keys.

Comment: Hmm. That's almost what I want. The thing is, I want to create an event that is triggered *only* by the Return/Enter key, not by selecting via mouse. In other words, you select an item from the list (or type one in), and then apply the item by pressing Return/Enter (or hitting an "Apply" button in my dialog)

Comment: I guess I still don't understand the question. Are you talking about selecting an item from the drop down menu? (because that would be a terrible UI if the mouse click and Enter key work differently) Or are you talking about using the enter key when focus is on the combo box and the drop down is closed? If this is the case, then is your combo box editable? Is focus on the text field being used as the editor? Post your SSCCE.